# Paginate dom elements with jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

I want add a simple pager(prev -- next) for paginate some html tables. I tried out few jquery pagination plugins, but they generate a more complex pagination system like

```
(<<first <prev 1,2,3,4,5 next> last>>).
```

I looking for something more basic and light. How can I do that with jquery?

Comment: that's incredibly broad!

Comment: There's an excellent video tutorial on how to do this here: youtube.com/phpapplied

Answer (score 1):

check this it works fine with me http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/jquery-quick-pagination/

very easy to use

```
 $("ul.pagination3").quickPagination({pagerLocation:"both",pageSize:"3"});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I need only prev|next buttons, not a pages list. Do you know if plugin allow that?